# Remove colon from form labels

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm using

```
{{ form_label(form.fieldName) }}
```

and it's generating label with colon (:) in the end. How to remove auto-adding it to labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the form rendering using [Form Theming](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html). What you will have to customize is the [form_label](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig) block.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Patt, the solution is:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block field_label %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if not compound %}
        {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'for': id}) %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if required %}
        {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if label is empty %}
        {% set label = name|humanize %}
    {% endif %}
    <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</label>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock field_label %}
```

Comment: Happy to help @Dhofca, maybe you could accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can use `vars.label` on the field :

```
<label for="{{ form.fieldName.vars.id }}">{{ form.fieldName.vars.label }}</label>
```